# Writing inequalities in r if statements

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I'm constructing a function in r. In the function, I am generating a random number and calling it x. I want my function to do different things:

- `If x is less than 0.1 (0 <= x < 0.1)`
- `If x is less than 0.2 (0.1 <= x < 0.2)`
- etc up to 1.

I want to write:

```
Myfunction = function() {   
    x = runif(1)

    if(0 <= x < 0.1) {
        do something...
    }

    if(0.1 <= x < 0.2) {
        do something... (etc)
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. How could I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use and (&) within your function. Instead of

```
if( 0.1 <= x < 0.1)
```

you want to use

```
if ( 0.1 <=x && x < 0.1)
```

Comment: probably best to use `&&` rather than `&` in this case

Comment: I have edited for consistency. I was not aware of the difference but after some review you make a good point as x has length 1

Answer (score 1):

```
if (x < 0.1) {
  # do smth
} else if (x < 0.2) {
  # do smth else
} else {
  # final smth
}
```

or for a single use case:

```
if (x < 0.2 && x >= 0.1) {
   # do-do-do
}
```