# R - How to write in specific column in a loop : nothing comes out

Tags: r, list, loops, if-statement

I'm working on a R program to automatically write a text in specific cell, in specific rows while being in a loop.

The each d$data.frame is cut into a maximum of 150 rows
The aim is to divide the document into 3 sections of 50 rows to put a name in column number 5. (made to give a task to someone specific)

What we have is :

d: a list of data.frames done by splitting a huge data base

- w: length of d $

```
for (i in 1:w)  {
  if   (nrow(102<d[[i]])&nrow(d[[i]])<150){
    d[[i]][1:50,c("Contact Owner")] <- 'Luc'  
    d[[i]][51:101,c("Contact Owner")] <- 'Bertha'
    d[[i]][102:150,c("Contact Owner")] <- 'Marc'
  } else 
    if (nrow(51<d[[i]])&nrow(d[[i]])<101){
      d[[i]] [1:50,c("Contact Owner")] <- 'Luc'
      d[[i]] [51:101,c("Contact Owner")] <- 'Bertha'
    } else 
      if  (nrow(1<d[[i]])&nrow(d[[i]])<50){
        d[[i]] [1:nrow(d[[i]]),c("Contact Owner")] <- 'Luc'}
break
  }
```

I keep on having this error message  **argument is of length zero**

thank you in advance for all the help :)

---

### More informations

---

I can't shqre the files I'm working on as they are private data but here are the current details I can give

- d is a list of 5 **data.frame** that was given by
  `d <- split(Scrapping,r)

d$1, d$2, d$3, d$4 are 150x16
d$5 is 10x16`

In the 5th column of each d$i I want to write names
row 1 -50: I would like Luc
row 51 -101: Bertha
row 102 -150: Marc

Yet the last d$i data.frame will often be less than 150 rows, so I want to put only names where there are other data.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Also [you can use use `$` with a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/dynamically-select-data-frame-columns-using-and-a-character-value), use `[[]]` instead; and [you can't use double inequalities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259979/writing-inequalities-in-r-if-statements), use `&` to combine tests

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easier option with `split` after creating a grouping vector with `gl`

```
d1 <- transform(d, newcol = paste0('name', as.integer(gl(nrow(d), 50, nrow(d)))))
split(d1, d1$newcol)
```

Comment: Would this still work considering that the column already exist ? Or should I remove it to create it as a new column ?

Comment: @Max if the column already exist, you can just do `split(d1, d1$yourcol)`

Answer (score 0):

I was able in the end to find a way to do so like this :

```
w <- length(d)
for (i in 1:w)  {
  d[[i]][1:50,c("Contact Owner")] = "Luc"  
  d[[i]][51:101,c("Contact Owner")] = "Bertha"
  d[[i]][102:150,c("Contact Owner")] = "Marc"
  d[[i]] <- with(d[[i]], d[[i]][!(`First Name` == "" | is.na(`First Name`)), ])   
}
```